Quartus FPGA critical path using timing report
I'm trying to understand how Quartus works to compile your design when you give it a time constraint (specifying clock period on .sdc file).
To find the critical path of my design using Quartus, why do I have to set the clock period such that there's minimum slack? As I change the clock period, why do the delays of each path change? What is actually happening to my compiled design when I change the clock period?

Quartus by default uses timing driven synthesis and fitting. What that means is that if the timing constraints are easy to meet, it will spend less time optimising the design and less time trying to find an optimal fit.
That means that if you lower the frequency in the timing constraints, then rerun the synthesis, it's likely you'll end up with a lower performing design - because meeting timing is good enough, no point it working harder than necessary to do that. You'll also notice the time spent running the tools reduces too.
Conversely if you make the timing constraints harder to meet, the tools will work harder and harder to try and accomplish the goal, eventually failing to do so, which is where you start getting negative slack values.

A negative setup slack means the delay from one register to the next is longer than the clock period (less any clock skew), which is sensitive to routing delays and process/temperature variations, hence measured on multiple timing corners.

A negative hold slack implies the signal changed too close to the clock edge, which is usually automatically fixed by the tools by increasing the routing length as long as there is enough setup slack and space to allow it.


If you want to find the worst case path in the design, you'll want to use the TimeQuest tools. You can run TimeQuest GUI from within Quartus which will allow you to amongst other things see details about the slowest paths in the design (path with least positive or most negative slack). You can also extract FMax information from this tool also  no need to change the constraints.
Bare in mind though that even tiny changes to the constraints or logic can wildly affect the timing performance in unpredictable ways as the fitter is essentially playing a massive game of whack-a-mole. So the slowest path may change each time, but you should get a sense with a bit of practice of which region of the design required work to either meet or improve timing.

Also, there is an option to randomize the starting conditions for the optimizer. If that is enabled, two consecutive runs will end up with wildly different timings, that has taken many people by surprise. For a design that is teetering on edge, that can be the deciding factor between pass/fail, but the results are not reproducible unless you generate and manage the random seed outside the synthesis process.

@SimonRichter Interesting, do you remember which option that is? From my experience Quartus seems to produce reproducable results if compiled in the same version from the same design files. There is a fitter seed parameter which is used to select the starting seed for the "psuedo-random" process, but as long as you don't change that value it stays consistent. In fact changing that starting seed by a small amount (e.g. change 72 to 73) can be very useful for improving timing as it doesn't actually seem to wildly change the results, only slightly tweaks them compared with a large change in seed.

(I'm using 22.1 currently, but was the same in 17.1)

exactly this one -- this can also be set to generate a new random number every time, and I've seen it activated in quite a few projects, where people were then confused about it.

@SimonRichter Ah I see, didn't know you could set it to be randomised, interesting.

Yes that makes sense. But how does Quartus do the optimizations? I’ve taken a look at the resource summary as I change to clock period. The number of ALUTs didn’t change, but the LAB did. So I’m assuming that Quartus is just laying out the resources differently but is using the same amount of them overall?

@AnjelicaY Quartus is a big black box so its very difficult to figure out what optimisations it is doing under the hood. Essentially it boils down to stuff getting placed in different locations in the FPGA, and also the routing between them changing. Sometimes you have the same amount of stuff but in different places, other times you might get more or less stuff if it e.g. duplicates registers to help meet timing.

@SimonRichter that’s also an interesting finding. Why would generating random optimization be useful? And why does Quartus randomize optimization anyways?

@AnjelicaY, optimization is localized, because there are too many parameters. After technology mapping, you end up with a network of primitives, and you need to assign locations to all of them, but for LUTs and FFs, there are thousands to millions of candidate positions. A good way to get started is to assign the I/Os first (these are usually constrained to single pads or at least groups), then work outwards from that, but it is possible to paint yourself into a corner because there are fewer routing resources than LEs, so it's better to start with some space in between and pack later.

@AnjelicaY, if the result of that fails timing, it needs to be redone with a different starting point (because the optimization algorithm itself is deterministic), and if you already know that a specific starting point will fail, you want to skip it. Randomizing the starting point gives you a chance to skip failing starting points without keeping a history.

@AnjelicaY, resource counts can differ slightly because optimization can duplicate nodes, e.g. if you have five signals and one of them is derived from the other four, then you only need four routing nets to bring the five signals to the other side if you copy the LUT.
